# Unknown use of a instruction mnemonic without a size suffix (x86_64)

Tags: assembly, x86, llvm, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am getting this error after writing some inline assembly in an llvm pass module:

```
<inline asm>:1:2: error: unkown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
        test %rsi, $1
        ^
```

My understanding is that this error means I am trying to use an operand size that the instruction doesn't support, or that the size is ambiguous. I carefully reviewed the Intel x86_64 Software Development Manual and I am fairly certain I am unambiguously specifying a "REX.W + F7 /0 id" or "TEST r/m64, imm32" operation. Do I need to be more explicit that I want the REX version? How?

Comment: Probably it's just whining that you aren't using AT&T syntax operand-size suffix in your `test` instruction. Try `testq`.

Comment: I think you probably meant to use `test $1, %rsi` .If using an immediate with test it needs to be the source operand. In AT&T syntax the source is on the left and destination on the right (reverse of Intel syntax)

Comment: Since you are testing the lower bit only I'd probably recommend `test $1, %esi`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Michael Petch pointed out, I was mixing up AT&T and Intel assembly. The operand order was reversed. Switching to `test $1, %rsi` resolved the issue.

Comment: Note that you'll get smaller code-size from `test $1, %sil` (4 bytes: REX+test+modrm+imm8).  There's no [`test r/m64, imm8` encoding, only a 32-bit immediate for 32-bit or 64-bit registers](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test), so you should use narrow registers with masks that are all zero in their upper bits anyway.  `test $1, %esi` would only save the REX prefix, but SIL saves more bytes.  (Reading low8 partial registers after writing a wider register doesn't have any partial-register penalty.)  You mention specifically aiming for the REX imm32 encoding in your Q, maybe for a padding...